# Eigenvalue of LTI System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, eigenfunctions, initial-value-problems

I'm sure I am overlooking something simple, but I can't figure it out.

For an LTI system with impulse response $h(t)$, we have $y(t) = x(t) * h(t)$. So 
$$ y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x(t-\tau)h(\tau)d\tau}. $$

If we consider the case of $x(t) = e^{st}$, then
$$ y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{s(t-\tau)}h(\tau)d\tau} $$
$$ = e^{st}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-s\tau}h(\tau)d\tau} $$
$$ = x(t) \mathcal{L}\lbrace{h(t)}\rbrace $$
$$ = H(s) x(t). $$

To my understanding, the above states that the transfer function $H(s)$ is the eigenvalue of the system corresponding to the eigenfunction $x(t) = e^{s t}$.

In an attempt to verify this in a more concrete case, I attempted to work through an example using the system
$$ y'(t) + y(t) = x(t)$$
with input $x(t) = e^{5 t}$ and initial value $y(0) = 0$.

Using the Laplace transform, I quickly was able to compute 
$$H(s) = \frac{1}{1+s}.$$
So for this input, $H(5) = \frac{1}{6}$.

Therefore I expect $y(t) = H(5)e^{5 t} = \frac{1}{6}e^{5 t}$, which is indeed a component of the output, but somewhere I have lost the transient response. Using normal methods of solving the equation, I calculate $y(t) = \frac{1}{6}e^{5t} - \frac{1}{6}e^{-t}$. Choosing the initial value carefully I can eliminate the other component of the response, but I was under the impression that the initial result held for null initial conditions.

Where have I gone wrong? I've got a feeling it is a missed assumption or some such, but I haven't been able to find my mistake.
Thanks.

**EDIT**: Some more information.

The initial value problem $y' + y = 0; y(0) = 0$ has solution $y(t) = 0$.

The impulse response of the system described by $y' + y = x$ is
$h(t) = e^{-t}u(t)$. Taking the convolution integral with $x(t) = e^{5t}$, I get $y(t) = \frac{1}{6}e^{5t}$, consistent with the result above. But $Y(s) = H(s)X(s) = \frac{1}{(s-5)(s+1)} = \frac{1}{6(s-5)} -\frac{1}{6(s+1)}$, which gives $y(t) = \frac{1}{6}e^{5t} - \frac{1}{6}e^{-t}$. These methods should give the same result for all time, so I must be misapplying them or otherwise missing something. I can't find the source of this inconsistency.

Comment: You are missing a $u(t)$ in all your input and output relationships in the second approach. See the details I added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand now. Just to check, with $x(t) = e^{5 t}$ (no unit step), we have $y(t) = \frac{1}{6} e^{5 t}$ and the eigenvalue approach is valid, while with $x(t) = e^{5 t} u(t)$ we have $y(t) = \frac{1}{6}e^{5 t} - \frac{1}{6}e^{-t}$ and the eigenvalue approach is invalid because adding the unit step makes $x(t)$ no longer an eigenfunction. Right?

Comment: Correct. Notice that the output to $x(t)=e^{at}u(t)$ is composed of two parts: a homogeneous response which is transient and a particular response which is steady state. The output calculated by the eigen-analysis is the same as the particular response (and often in Fourier analysis is referred to as the steady-state response, where we deal with complex exponential inputs $e^{j\omega t}$) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a $u(t)$ in all your input and output relationships in the second approach. $e^{5t}$ is not equal to $e^{5t}u(t)$ (well, after the transient response is damped you may assume there has not been a $u(t)$ and use the eigen approach). Notice that $\frac{1}{s+a}$ is the LT of $e^{-at}u(t)$.

"I was under the impression that the initial result held for null initial conditions"

This is a valid observation and is because:

> A system described by ordinary differential equations with constant coefficients is only linear if the initial conditions are zero.

So any other initial condition except zero will make the system nonlinear, in which case the eigen-analysis is not valid anymore.

We can do something to make the system *look* like a linear system for $t\ge0$ by adjusting $y(0)$ such that the transient response is canceled.
Since the LT is $$sY(s)-y(0)+Y(s)=\frac{1}{s-5}$$ we have $y(t)=(y(0)-\frac{1}{6})e^{-t}u(t)+\frac{1}{6}e^{5t}u(t)$. Hence, with $y(0)=\frac{1}{6}$ the transient response is canceled for $t>0$. Note that $t=0$ is not an "initial" condition in this context (but $t=-\infty$ is).

Comment: This is what I thought. But in this case the eigen-analysis only works if the initial condition is $y(0) = \frac{1}{6}$, so I still don't understand why the other term shows up in one solution but not the other.

Comment: The steady-state conditions is when the impact of initial values are damped out. So you can see as $t\to\infty$, the two become equal. The steady-state solution conforms with the particular solution of the differential equation. The homogeneous solution (which is transient) is only excited by the natural frequencies and the initial values (which if you assume zero will make the transient solution zero).